# Quando é que "e" se pronuncia /ɐj/?

Tags: português-europeu, pronúncia

Quando é que "e" se pronuncia /ɐj/? Por exemplo, nas seguintes palavras:

- sexto (contrasta com "cesto")
- telha (mas não "velha", que parece ser uma exceção)
- tem (aqui nasalizado)

Comment: Não entendo o símbolo fonético usado.

Comment: @Centaurus Vê por exemplo a pronúncia de Portugal aqui: http://forvo.com/word/seja/#pt

Comment: Em pt-BR, "velha" se pronuncia com "é", enquanto que as outras palavras que você mencionou são pronunciadas com "ê". Note, entretanto, que em algumas regiões, como no Rio de Janeiro, "sexto" pode ser pronunciado como "sêichto", e que o som "em" de "tem" é em geral realizado como um ditongo nasal "eim".

Comment: @ArthurAzevedoDeAmorim  Concordo, pode ser pronunciado "sêichto" mas normalmente nós, cariocas, pronunciamos "sechto" ao contrário de paulistas, mineiros e gaúchos que pronunciam "sesto"

Comment: É mais fácil percebir a diferença ao princípio desta canção (*primeiro* e *desejo* soam como *primairo* e *desaijo*): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTVv5Pv6Z7k No mirandês, muitos das vogais *E* do português ou do espanhol são e escrevem-se *A*, poderia ser um sotaque do norte o nordeste?

Comment: @guifa Às vezes em Lisboa, também se ouve simplesmente [ɐ], por exemplo "sejo" como /sɐʒu/. Mas essa pronunciação não é muito standard; lembro-me que quando o dicionário da Verbo saiu, foi muito criticado por registar algumas palavras dessa forma.

Comment: Vide https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/artigos/rubricas/controversias/o-positivo-e-o-negativo-do-dicionario-da-academia-das-ciencias-de-lisboa/1837

Comment: @Artefacto Interessantíssimo artigo, obrigado.  Estou agora a integrar indicações de pronúncia na edição eletrónica do dicionário asturiano, e o artigo menciona algumas coisas que são bonas para considerar no processo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O ***em*** nasal no fim de palavra ou seguido de hífen — como em *bem, bem-amado, tem, nascem* — é o mais fácil. Para a maioria dos falantes em Portugal é um ditongo, /ɐ̃j/, que rima com *mãe*; mas para alguns, que eu ouço aqui em Setúbal e segundo o Artefacto também ocorre no Algarve, é um *e* nasal,/ẽ/, mas o que eu ouço é um pouco mais longo que o *en* de *d**en**te*, por exemplo. No Brasil também é ditongo, mas parece-me que não rima bem com *mãe*: diria que é mais /ẽj/, apesar de este ditongo não figurar neste [artigo da Wikipédia sobre fonologia portuguguesa](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonologia_da_l%C3%ADngua_portuguesa). Comparem a pronuncia de [*bem*](http://forvo.com/word/bem/#pt) e [*mãe*](http://forvo.com/word/m%C3%A3e/#pt) no Brasil e em Portugal (nestes links como em todos os que se seguem, pode-se ouvir a palavra indicada a ser pronunciada por portugueses, brasileiros ou ambos).

Parece que todos os falantes do português pronunciam o ***e*** como /ɐj/ em ***e***x-qualquer coisa:

> [Ex-mulher](http://forvo.com/word/ex-mulher/#pt), [ex-marido](http://forvo.com/word/o_ex-marido/#pt), [ex-ministro](http://forvo.com/search/ex-ministro/).

Creio que em Portugal, /ɐj/ é também a pronúncia universal de ***e*** em [*s**e**xta*](http://forvo.com/word/texto/#pt), [t**e**xto](http://forvo.com/word/texto/#pt), cont**e**xto, pret**e**xto, **ê**xtase e derivados. E já sabemos, vejam o comentário do Arthur à pergunta e ouçam um brasileiro a pronunciar *sexta* no link acima, que no Rio também há quem pronuncie *sexta* assim. Não sei se existem mais palavras com este padrão, isto é ***ex*** tónico seguido de consoante.

Os restantes casos de ***e*** pronunciado /ɐj/ parecem-me ser um fenómeno exclusivo do português europeu e possivelmente africano.

Quando a palavra começa por ***ex*** + consoante (a consoante é sempre surda) em que **ex** não é tónico, como em [*exclusão*](http://forvo.com/word/exclus%C3%A3o_social/#pt), [exposição](http://forvo.com/word/exposi%C3%A7%C3%A3o/#pt), existem em Portugal as pronúncias /ɐjʃ/, /ɨʃ/ e simplesmente /ʃ/, com preferência, diria eu, para as duas últimas. Parece-me que no Brasil é sempre /eʃ/ (especialmente no Rio) ou /es/.

Nos restantes casos é geralmente o /e/ tónico (como em [*s**e**r*](http://forvo.com/word/ser/#pt)) que é ditonguizado para /ɐj/ ou passa simplesmente a /ɐ/ nos conjuntos *ech, ej, elh* e *enh*. O ***e*** aberto, /ɛ/ (fl**e**cha) normalmente não é ditonguisado. O ***e*** fechado é ditonguisado por muitos falantes nos conjuntos **ech, ej**, como em [*fecho*](http://forvo.com/word/fecho/#pt) (substantivo), [*azulejo*](http://forvo.com/word/azulejo/#pt). É possível que seja ditonguisado por algumas pessoas também em *mexo, mexas*. Mas nada disto é universal: muita gente pronuncia /e/.

Nos conjuntos *elh*, como *telha, coelho, fedelho, pingarelho* parece-me que a ditonguisação é mais ligeira ou inexistente. E novamente muita gente diz /e/:

> /[’oɾɐ(j)ʎɐ](http://forvo.com/word/orelha/#pt)/, /’oɾɐʎɐ/ ou /’oɾeʎɐ/; /’kwɐʎu/, [/’kwɐ(j)ʎu/ ou /’kweʎu/](http://forvo.com/word/coelho/#pt).

Há aqui pelo menos uma exceção ao ***e*** aberto permanecer aberto. *Grelha* é pronunciado por algumas pessoas como /’gɾɐ(j)ʎɐ/, por outros como /’gɾɛʎɐ/. Mas realmente creio que toda a gente diz /’vɛʎɐ/ e não /’vɐ(j)ʎɐ/. Não me lembro de mais palavras com ***e*** aberto em *elh*.

Finalmente, em o ***e*** tónico em *enh*, como em [*tenho*](http://forvo.com/word/tenho/#pt), cenho, desenho. Creio que quase toda a gente pronuncia o ***e*** como /ɐ/. Alguma ditonguisação que haja é muito ligeira. Creio que pouca gente pronuncia este ***e*** como /e/. Possivelmente pronunciam-no como /e/ os mesmos que pronunciam *em* como /ẽ/.

### Possível distribuição da ditongação (a norte) e não ditongação (a sul)

O mapa abaixo é baseado em Lindley Cintra, “Nova Proposta de Classificação dos Dialectos Galego-Portugueses”, Boletim de Filologia, 1971 (p. 16) [(disponível no Instituto Camões)](http://cvc.instituto-camoes.pt/hlp/biblioteca/novaproposta.pdf)

[image]

Além disso, as fronteiras na pronúncia do ***e*** em palavras como *tenho*, *espelho*, *desejo* e *o fecho* não tem que coincidir. Eu sou um exemplo disso. Eu cresci na zona de Torres Vedras, a uns 50 km a norte de Lisboa, que pelos vistos fica na zona creme, pois o pessoal mais velho lá pronunciava *peixe* como /’peʃɨ/, *queijo* como /’keʒu/, e o sufixo *eiro* era sempre pronunciado como /eɾu/: *carneiro* era /kɐɾ’neɾu/, *padeira* era /pa’deɾɐ/. Ora, eu pronuncio o ditongo neste tipo de palavras, mas tendo a manter o ***e*** como /e/ em palavras como *espelho, desejo* e *o fecho*; mas pronuncio o ***e*** como /ɐ/ em *tenho, lenha, senha*, etc.

Comment: Não tinha pensado nessa diferença entre "enh" e "elh". Há de facto pessoas como o Jorge Coelho que dizem /tɐ(j)ɲu/, mas /kõseʎu/ (mas no Algarve é /e/ em ambos os casos e mesmo em "tem", que é pronunciado /tẽ/). A prolação com /e/ será sempre regional em Portugal, contudo; a tua resposta limita-se a referir "algumas pessoas". Quando a não haver ditonguisação em "enh" (e portanto haver um "senha-sanha merger"), já não tenho tanta certeza.

Comment: Por outro lado, houve aquele artigo do Miguel Sousa Tavares... :p

Comment: Qual é o artigo do MST? Eu tenho ideia que a variação é em boa parte regional, mas não sei o suficiente para dizer onde é que predomina uma forma ou a outra. Tenho a ideia que a ditonguisação é uma coisa lisboeta que provavelmente se está a expandir. No resto do sul era até o ditongo /ej/ que passava a /e/. Eu tenho até dificuldade em dizer /tɐjɲu/, mas ainda assim eu tenho lá uns "quase toda a gente", "dintoguisação ligeira" para não me comprometer demasiado. Achas que o /tɐjɲu/ é bastante comum? A infopédia indica os enhos todos como /ɐ(j)ɲu/

Comment: O artigo está por trás de uma paywall, mas o que aconteceu é que ele queria dizer "sanha", mas escreveu "senha". Vê [aqui](http://linguagista.blogs.sapo.pt/senha-por-sanha-lenho-por-lanho-1301344). Em relação à evolução ter sido /e/ -> /ɐ/ -> /ɐj/, tenho quase certeza de que estás engando. Foi antes /e/ -> /ɐj/ e (agora?) há um /ɐ/ algo controverso (vê o artigo no ciberduvidas que citei acima). Quanto a "tenho", tenho de convir que embora /tɐjɲu/  não me cause nenhuma estranheza (ao contrário de /ɐ/ em ovelha ou, especialmente, seja, que ainda se assim se ouvem), /tɐɲu/ há de ser o mais comum.

Comment: Lol, se o pessoal continuasse a dizer /seɲɐ/ nada disto teria acontecido. Eu não digo que foi /e/ -> /ɐ/ -> /ɐj/. Onde é julgas que viste isso? Não sei como é que foi, mas também tou mais a ver /e/ passar primeiro para /ɐj/. Mas no caso dos *enh* o /j/ mal se ouve ou não tá mesmo lá.

Comment: O artigo intitula-se "Lisboetices e Incoerências". Será que ele acha que o /e/ > /ɐj/ é ou começou por ser uma coisa lisboeta? ***ei*** foi /ɐj/ em Lisboa antes de alastrar para outras regiões. Creio que no norte era /ej/ e no sul /e/. E continua a ser para muita gente.

Comment: Acho que falta dizer que "em", para se converter em /ɐ̃j/, precisa de ser sílaba tónica final (compara "sempre" com "sem"). Os outros (à exceção do "ex" inicial) parecem ser em sílabas tónicas também, mas pode ser simplesmente uma consequência de o som /e/ aparecer em sílabas tónicas.

Comment: Pois falta. Não precisa é de ser tónico: *nascem*. Também ocorre em *textual* e coisas assim que eu incluí nos derivados. Quanto aos outros eu já digo que é tónico, mas na verdade não tem que ser: *coelheira, joelhada*.

Comment: Curioso que em "de vez em quando", "em" se pronuncia /e/.

Comment: Juntas o *em* à palavra seguinte: "de vez enquando," "entodo o caso"...

Comment: `É possível que seja ditonguisado por algumas pessoas também em mexo, mexas.` - confere.

Comment: @Artefacto Juntei uma proposta de distribuição regional das pronúncias.

Answer (score 1):

Na pronuncia padrão o /e/ (E fechado) pronuncia-se como /ɐj/ (ditongo EI) antes de sons palatais, bem como a sua versão nasal, /ɐ̃j/, em final de palavra. Ou seja nas seguintes situações:

- O ditongo EI é sempre pronunciado como /ɐj/.
- A silaba EX é pronunciada como /ɐjʃ/
- E fechado tonico seguido de CH pronuncia-se como /ɐj/.
- E fechado tonico seguido de J pronuncia-se como /ɐj/.
- E fechado tonico seguido de NH pronuncia-se como /ɐ/.
- E fechado tonico seguido de LH pronuncia-se como /ɐ/.
- -EM em final de palavra pronuncia-se como /ɐ̃j/. Também se aplica
  a algumas palavras derivadas (ou aparentemente derivadas) de bem:
  Benfica, benzinho, etc.
  (Regras retiradas daqui: https://european-portuguese.info/vowels)

Portanto note-se que quando seguido de de I, NH ou LH o ditongo perde a semivogal /j/ e passa a um simples /ɐ/.

Além disso este fenomeno apenas afeta o E fechado, o E aberto mantém-se, por exemplo velho mantém-se /vɛʎu/.

Basicamente isto deriva de uma tendencia de dissimilação, em que sons proximos se afastaram. Este fenomeno não ocorre em todos os sotaques. Por exemplo em Coimbra não ocorre no caso do LH, e noutras regiões não acontece de todo.