# Sounds: Why 'e' in some words become 'a' (uh) or 'ê' (en)? Why not 'é' (eh)?

Tags: pronúncia, regionalismo

Can "Lenha" be pronounced as "lanha" or "lênha"? Why not "lénha"? More explicitly: Why the **e** sound in some words become an **a** (uh) sound or an **ê** (en) sound? Why not an **é** (eh) sound?

A few words where I believe this difference in pronunciation happens:

- l**e**nho
- verm**e**lho
- sobranc**e**lha
- castanh**e**iro
- franc**e**lho
- vel**e**nho
- verd**e**lha
- sout**e**nho
- m**e**nhir ?

In *b**a**nho*, *m**a**nha* and *reb**a**nho*, for example, I assume the **a** is never pronounced as **ê**, or am I wrong?

I assume that the difference between **a** and **ê** may reside in the proximity of *-nho(a/e/i)* or *-lho(a/e/i)* and perhaps in the [standard pronunciation of Portuguese](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/ainda-a-pronuncia-padrao/21881) (which some may refer to the latter (**ê**) as the [most proper pronunciation (from Coimbra?)](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/a-pronuncia-de-coimbra/21110)).

### Edit

Relating to this question (thanks Jacinto):

[Quando é que "e" se pronuncia /ɐj/?](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/1386/156)

I'm adding a few more examples:

- t**e**lha
- co**e**lho
- fed**e**lho
- gr**e**lha
- v**e**nha

Not having *-lh(vowel)* or *-nh(vowel)* and also possibly being pronounced differently according to the region:

- **e**x-ministro
- s**e**xta
- t**e**xto
- **ê**xtase
- fl**e**cha

Comment: [This question](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1386/quando-%C3%A9-que-e-se-pronuncia-%C9%90j/1390#1390) may address your doubts to some extent. Maybe you'd like to focus your own question in light of it. "Menhir"? You meant *mentir*, right?

Comment: Hehe :) [menhir](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/menhir)=menir, maybe it's not an usual word.

Comment: Regions like Minho which is in the north of Portugal often pronounce 'e' as it was 'a', but I believe that there no such word in portuguese that the 'e' is pronounced as 'a'

Comment: At most is just a north pronounce

Answer (score 5):

My answer concerns ptBR only.

**In ptBR the "e" in these words is never pronounced as an "a" sound.**  The "e" in  **"grelha"** and **"flecha"** is pronounced as **an open "e"** ("é").  The "e" in all other words is always pronounced "ê".  Of importance is the fact that about half of those words are rarely used in ptBR (lenho, francelho, velenho, verdelho, soutenho, menhir).

Lenha is pronounced l**ê**nha. Why not "l**é**nha" ?  Because that's the way it is pronounced. Simple as that.

Edit - The "a" before "nh" is always pronounced as "ã"