# "Textículo" (de texto pequeno) é informal ou formal?

Tags: significado, informalidade

Uma vez vi alguém utilizando a expressão ***textículo*** para se referir a um texto minúsculo.

Essa palavra realmente existe, ou é algo informal?

Comment: No Vocabulário Ortográfico da Língua Portuguesa, o termo textículo não foi encontrado. No entanto, outros diminutivos com o mesmo sufixo foram encontrados: febrícula e versículo. O Aulete e no Priberam não reconhecem textículo. Parece-me algo informal.

Comment: É um trocadalho :)

Comment: Claro, é um trocadilho.

Answer (score 5):

[Embora uma pesquisa rápida no Google tenha produzido **17.500 resultados**](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=text&rlz=1C1ARAB_enBR495BR495&oq=text&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j0l2j69i65j0.2821j0j8&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=%22text%C3%ADculo%22), a palavra ainda não consta nos grandes dicionários como o Aurélio, por exemplo, e por esse ponto de vista é informal.

É possível que venha a ser incluída em um futuro próximo apesar da confusão que pode causar na língua falada por ser homófona de **"testículo"**, e se for usada em um contexto não muito claro.  Por exemplo: "eu trouxe um textículo para te mostrar".

**ADDENDUM**

- Se o voto negativo foi devido à minha afirmação de que "textículo" e "testículo" são palavras homófonas, devo dizer que são homófonas no local onde vivo - Rio de Janeiro. É bem provável que em outros estados do Brasil o "x" e o "s" sejam pronunciados de modo diferente. Em Portugal, acredito que sejam também homófonas e cabe aos nossos colegas de ultramar confirmar ou não.

Comment: Em pt-PT não são homófonas: «teistículo» e «tstículo». Da mesma forma, texto lê-se «teisto», teste lê-se «téste», e testei lê-se «tstei».

Comment: Centaurus, em Portugal não são homófonas, mas são muito parecidas: *testículo* é /t**ɨ**ʃˈtikulu/; e *textículo* é  /t**ɐj**ʃˈtikulu/ ou possivelmente entre alguns falantes do sul /t**e**ʃˈtikulu/ (como no Rio). Mas eu já calculava que no Brasil seriam homófonas. Vê [onde é que "e" se pronuncia /ɐj/](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1386/quando-%C3%A9-que-e-se-pronuncia-%C9%90j).

Comment: @Jacinto  Não sei se são homófonas em todo o Brasil.  Apenas o carioca faz o "s" chiado, que faz com que fique similar ao "x".  Os outros brasileiros tendem a pronunciar "tessstículos"

Comment: Só tinha pensado na pronúncia do ***e***. Mas estive a ouvir no forvo [cesta](https://pt.forvo.com/word/cesta/#pt) e [sexta](https://pt.forvo.com/word/sexta-feira/#pt), e no Brasil parecem-me iguais mesmo com o ***s*** não chiado.

Comment: @Jacinto   Ah, queres dizer que embora diferente dos cariocas, os paulistas (e outros) pronunciam o "x" de "texto" como se fosse um "s"?  É possível.  Não me recordo de ter ouvido "texto" e "sexta" pronunciados dessa forma, mas é possível.  Nem sempre presto atenção às diferenças linguísticas quando estou em outro estado do Brasil.

Comment: Foi essa a minha suposição, sim. O que ouço no forvo parece confirmar. [Texto](https://pt.forvo.com/word/texto/#pt), só lá há um mineiro, que a mim me soa como tessto. *Sexta* tens aos montes no link acima.

Comment: Para os casos citados, no Rio pronunciam S e X como se fosse X (com chiado de texugo), no restante no país o S e X tem som de S.

Answer (score 2):

***Textículo*** em português e espanhol e *texticule* em francês e até em três ou quatro publicações em inglês têm sido usados em círculos literários, sobretudo para designar um texto literário breve ou de fraca qualidade, não uma mensagem deixada num post-it ou o texto num rótulo de uma garrafa. É uma palavra rara em todas as línguas. Em português aparece apenas em quinze livros no Google Books, e de oito dicionários em que procurei, encontrei-a apenas na [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/text%C3%ADculo):

> 1. texto breve, de dimensão reduzida
> 2. texto pouco importante ou de fraca qualidade

Não encontrei a palavra em dicionários ingleses, nem no Larousse ou Real Academia Española. Agora, uma palavra não precisa de autorização do dicionário para existir: foi dita e entendida, logo existe. *Textinho* ou *textito* nem na Infopédia vêm. *Heterocedasticidade* também não, mas é uma palavra usada em análise estatística.

Estas palavras são usadas do mesmo modo em todas estas línguas e devem ter origem comum e influenciado-se mutuamente, pelo que a palavra portuguesa é melhor compreendida neste contexto internacional. Segundo [Lauro Zavala, *Cartografías del cuento y la minificción* (2004)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=kSWNAwAAQBAJ&pg=PA351&dq=text%C3%ADculo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiOyNqFx_PQAhVDPCYKHUAjCtcQ6AEIfjAQ#v=onepage&q=text%C3%ADculo&f=false) foi o argentino [Julio Cortázar (1914-84)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julio_Cort%C3%A1zar) seguido mais tarde pelo mexicano [José Agustín (1944-)](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jos%C3%A9_Agust%C3%ADn) quem propuseram o termo *textículo* para referirem “textos narrativos o poéticos muy breves (200 a 1000 palabras)”. Também o francês Michel Tournier (1924-2016) chamava *texticules* aos seus “pequenos textos onde ele exprime de forma frequentemente brincalhona as suas admirações por uma obra, artista […]” [(Wikipédia, tradução minha)](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Tournier)

Parece-me que a palavra foi intencionalmente brincalhona. Por um lado é de derivação culta: o sufixo *-culo*, tal como a sua variante *-ulo*, é típico de palavras que entraram na língua por via culta, sob a forma de importações tardias do latim, latinismos e neologismos científicos (Houaiss, Lisboa 2003, verbetes *-culo* e *-ulo*). Por outro lado a semelhança com *testículo* dá-lhe um tom brejeiro.

Por vezes é o autor que chama *textículo* ao seu próprio texto; creio que para sugerir brincalhona e modestamente que o que escreveu é de pouca importância. Por exemplo, [Públio Athayde, em *Articulando* (2009)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=gKlWBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA18&dq=text%C3%ADculo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiW3MbDwvPQAhXI7yYKHTuRAdEQ6AEIVTAI#v=onepage&q=text%C3%ADculo&f=false) (ênfase minha em todas as citações):

> Para situar os desavisados que lerem este **textículo** em tempos remotos, eis o fato: Adelir de Carli, padre católico, voou preso a balões e desapareceu no litoral de Santa Catarina na noite de domingo, 20 de abril de 2008.

Já [Nuno Júdice em *ABC da Crítica* (2012)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=lxD4lRLKfysC&pg=PT17&dq=text%C3%ADculo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiW3MbDwvPQAhXI7yYKHTuRAdEQ6AEIIjAB#v=onepage&q=text%C3%ADculo&f=false) emprega *textículo* depreciativamente para se referir a crítica literária que ele acha sem grande valor. Também [Francisco Carrasco, em *Medíocre Florêncio*, (2015)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=TfuGCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA187&dq=text%C3%ADculo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivpZTbz_7QAhUCtBQKHUNQBcYQ6AEIMjAD#v=onepage&q=text%C3%ADculo&f=false) usa *textículo* depreciativamente:

> Sentou-se e leu o que havia escrito naquele dia, tudo que parecera bom, agora lhe era simplesmente um **textículo** amador.

E encontrei um único exemplo, de 1946, o mais antigo em qualquer das línguas, [(*As Américas antes dos Europeus* de Luís Amaral)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=_xJmAAAAMAAJ&q=text%C3%ADculo&dq=text%C3%ADculo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiW3MbDwvPQAhXI7yYKHTuRAdEQ6AEIpgEwFQ), em que *textículo* designa um trecho de texto numerado numa obra, à laia dos versículos da Bíblia.

> [..] o *Pop Buj* refere a unidade de língua: “todos tinham uma só maneira de falar” (**textículo 42** da Sétima Tradição)
>   […]
>   Refere-os o *Popol Buj*. Depois de descrever a confusão dos povos, diz a Sétima Tradição, no **textículo 40**: “Então […]

Quanto à informalidade, pelo que vi, parece-me que a palavra é mais informal que formal, mas ainda assim relativamente neutra. Mas para mim o seu valor acrescentado está precisamente no tom algo brincalhão e ligeiramente depreciativo. Simplesmente para referir em tom neutro a dimensão do texto já temos imensas opções: *texto curto; escrevi **umas linhas/uma nota** sobre o assunto*, etc. Na maior parte dos usos fora do Google Books, pareceu-me que o motivo do uso era sobretudo a semelhança com *testículo*, como explicitamente [neste blog](http://philosophia-aton.blogspot.pt/2010/11/entre-testiculos-e-texticulos-vamos.html). Noutros caso, [como neste outro blog](http://amalscheleschthing.blogspot.pt/2016/09/texticulo.html), *textículo* é simplesmente o título do texto; para título genérico de um texto também já tínhamos imensas opções: *crónica, história, historieta, reflexões*, etc., só que não teriam a brejeirice de *textículo*.

Passa por vezes por aí a ideia que uma palavra é desaconselhável ou até errada. Isto é uma visão equivocada. O que há é palavras que são apropriadas à comunicação que o locutor quer estabelecer, e palavras que não o são. Por exemplo, inspirando-me na resposta do Centaurus, eu poderia dizer *tenho um textículo para vos mostrar* se quisesse gerar perplexidade e provocar riso ao mostrar o texto; já dizer num funeral ao cônjuge do morto *preparei um textículo para ler* não teria lá muita graça.

Answer (score 1):

No português brasileiro, já ouvi tal **textículo**; usado em tom de brincadeira.

Até o corretor insiste em corrigir, este pensou que escrevi *testículo*, o trocadilho.

Encontrei a palavra somente no [Infopédia](https://www.infopedia.pt/dicionarios/lingua-portuguesa/text%C3%ADculo), mas é difícil encontrar a flexão dos graus dos substantivos no dicionário. Isto reforça as variações e dúvidas sobre as palavras flexionadas.

Se fizer uma busca pelo [trends](https://www.google.com/trends/explore?date=all&q=text%C3%ADculo,textinho), **textinho** é mais comum.

Geralmente a flexão de grau sintética (adicionando o sufixo), no caso do *textículo* ou *textinho*, poderá dar abertura para outras interpretações, já na analítica é mais difícil de ocorrer.

Acredito que na dúvida entre a informalidade ou formalidade da palavra, optar pela flexão de grau na forma analítica (adicionando um adjetivo), **texto pequeno** é mais segura. A abertura para outras interpretações não convém em um texto formal, onde precisamos passar mais clareza (e talvez até seriedade) na comunicação.

Se um dia a palavra ficar *famosa*, ela virará um futuro *versículo*, *cartão*, *portão*, seu significado estará em vários dicionários e poderemos usar com mais segurança.

Comment: "eu não usei" ou "eu não sei"?

Answer (score 1):

Olá. A palavra "textículo" não existe em dicionários da língua portuguesa. Aqui no Brasil é considerado errado falar "textículo" para "texto pequeno", realmente consideramos que a palavra não existe, então não pode ser classificada como formal ou informal. Usamos "textinho" de modo informal e "pequeno texto" de modo formal.

Algumas pessoas com menor escolaridade podem falar "textículo" por falta de conhecimento, mas no geral é errado.

Tome cuidado para não confundir com a palavra homófona "testículo", que se refere a uma parte da estrutura genital masculina.

Espero que tenha ajudado :)