# Diferentes modos de pronunciar "alguém"/"ninguém" em pt-PT. Regionalismos?

Tags: português-europeu, pronúncia, diferenças

Percebo que os falantes de pt-PT pronunciam o "e" da palavra "ninguém" de duas formas diferentes. Alguns o pronunciam de forma bem semelhante ao que se ouve no Brasil [gém] enquanto outros, formam talvez um ditongo [gain]. Não tenho conhecimento suficiente de fonética para dar nome aos bois, mas para pronunciar a palavra como ditongo (ou semelhante a um ditongo) há que se abrir mais a boca e o palato mole parece se elevar.

Um exemplo do primeiro modo de pronunciar, seria o da cantora Milú em [**Cantiga da Rua**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gE6_JStJtTk) em 0':45" e em 1':26".  Como exemplo do que a mim soa como um ditongo, seria a pronuncia do vocalista da [**Estudantina Universitária de Coimbra**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8PvW1e8rFOw) em 1':07", 1':49" e 1':57".

Qual exatamente seria a diferença entre as duas pronuncias, em símbolos da IPA.
Essa diferença é explicada como decorrente de regionalismo? Grau de instrução? Grau de formalidade?  Onde em Portugal é mais comum ouvir-se um ditongo na pronuncia dessas palavras e de outras semelhantes?

Comment: Não te terás enganado num dos links? Eu ouço o ditongo /ɐ̃j/  (rima com *mãe*) nas duas canções. Creio que já tens a resposta a esta pergunta em ["Quando é que "e" se pronuncia /aj/?"](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1386/quando-%C3%A9-que-e-se-pronuncia-%C9%90j). Existe de facto a pronúncia  do *-em* também como monotongo /ẽ/, como em *d**en**te*, mas não o ouço nessa canções. Aos meus ouvidos esse *-em* também é ditongo no Brasil (mas possivelmente há muita variação regional) mas mais fechado, /ẽj/ e não /ɐ̃j/, como já observo na outra pergunta.

Comment: É, eu sinto o mesmo que o Jacinto, não me soam diferentes. A cantora Milú tem um sotaque mais queque "lisboêta", mas o «ninguém» não me parece diferente.

Comment: @ANevesthinksSEisevil O Centaurus [perguntou](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/q/8761/2764) sobre o que exatamente você quis dizer com "queque".

Comment: Eu vi, obrigado. :)

Answer (score 1):

O som só se parece com o ditongo. A lingua se preserva pela escrita, na gramática. A pronuncia sofre pequenas alteraçoes pelo regionalismo. Voce mesmo respondeu sua pergunta. Entao é irrelevante se tem relaçao com grau de instruçao, desde que a gramatica siga correta.