# É correto falar "vais de <algum lugar>"?

Tags: português-europeu, preposições, transitividade-verbal, verbos-transitivos

Eu fui perguntado uma vez em Portugal "Vais de Porto Alegre?" pela agente de imigração. Eu (brasileiro) normalmente perguntaria "Vens de Porto Alegre?". Está correto usar o verbo "ir" usando a preposição "de"?

Comment: vir de algum lugar: vir.  Vens de Porto Alegre? Alguém está confundindo vir e ir. :) Vais a lum lugar [do verbo ir] Vais para o Brasil? [verbo ir]

Comment: Gabriel, quão familiarizado estás tu com o sotaque de Portugal? Pergunto-me se terás ouvido bem. No sotaque de grande parte de Portugal, incluindo Lisboa, *vens* soa como *vães* (rima com *mães*), e os nossos sons nasais não são "tão nasais" como no Brasil. Daí ele poder ter dito *vens* com pronúncia *vães*, com nasalação inferior à normal do Brasil, e tu perceberes *vais*. Seria possível? Também me surpreende ele ter-te tratado por tu numa situação profissional. És muito novinho?

Comment: @Jacinto na ocasião eu tinha 26 anos. Eu viajo para Portugal com uma certa frequência, porém não tenho tanta familiaridade com o Português de Portugal. Acredito que o sotaque é que deve ter me confundido. Se ela disse "vens" como "vães" mais a típica "desnasalisação" portuguesa, deve ter soado mesmo como "vais" para mim.

Comment: @Jacinto Poderia pra escrever o seu comentário como resposta pra mim poder aceitar ela?

Comment: @GabrielDiego   Não leve a mal, não gosto de apontar erros em comentários, mesmo porque meu português também não é lá essas coisas.  Mas "pra mim poder aceitar ela"  dói nos ouvidos.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Vais de (algum lugar)* até é possível, mas não na situação descrita. Creio que neste aspeto nem haverá diferença entre Portugal e Brasil. Imagina que a Ana sabe que o Beto viaja frequentemente entre Lisboa e Porto:

> Beto: Vou a Londres no mês que vem.
>   Ana: Ah, vais de Lisboa ou do Porto?

Outra possibilidade:

> Vais de Lisboa ao Porto em duas horas, na boa. (= é possível ir de Lisboa ao Porto em duas horas.)

Mas nada disto se aplica à tua situação, em que a única coisa que eu esperaria, aqui em Portugal, é *vens de Porto Alegre?* Ou melhor, de um agente do Estado dirigindo-se profissionalmente a um adulto, esperaria *vem de Porto Alegre?*

Agora, o senhor pode ter resolvido inventar. Ou pode ter-se atrapalhado: por exemplo, entre um *vais seguir para outro destino?* ou coisa assim e um *vens de Porto Alegre?* ter saído *vais de Porto Alegre?* Haverá sempre a possibilidade de ele ter dito *vens* ou *vem*, e tu teres ouvido *vais* por falta de familiaridade com o nosso sotaque. Nomeadamente, na região de Lisboa, *vem* é normalmente pronunciado como *vãe*; aliás, em fim de palavra, qualquer *-em* é pronunciado como *-ãe* (vê [esta pergunta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/1386/quando-%C3%A9-que-e-se-pronuncia-%C9%90j)). E já li algures, mas não consigo localizar agora, que a nasalidade do português europeu é menos forte que a do brasileiro. Estes dois aspetos ajudariam a que um *vens* dum lisboeta chegasse *vais* aos ouvidos dum brasileiro pouco acostumado ao sotaque de Lisboa. Para ver se isto tem alguma razoabilidade, podes ouvir no Forvo portugueses a pronunciar [vem](https://forvo.com/word/vem/#pt), [bem](https://forvo.com/word/bem/#pt), [também](https://forvo.com/word/tamb%C3%A9m/#pt), [eu também](https://forvo.com/word/eu_tamb%C3%A9m/#pt). Também tens um *alguém* e *meu bem* na canção [amar pelos dois](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qotooj7ODCM) e uma porção de palavras terminadas em *em* no [telemóveis](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DWoA-7kF5R4)